# Configuring the Resolution of Jenkins Slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a Plugin on Jenkins which lets us control the resolution of the slave.

My application requires a min resolution of 1600x900 but when i perform a headless run the resolution is reverted to 1024x268

I'm running windows 7 on the slave.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something in Jenkins that depends on having access to the window system, perhaps you should set up a JNLP slave.

Then log into the slave host from GUI, fire up the browser and navigate to http://$JENKINS_URL/computer/SLAVENAME and use one of presented ways to start a slave agent. Because the agent is started in a GUI session, it will have access to the window system, it is able to draw windows and obtain screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to schedule the runs on a periodic basis without any manual intervention. could this be achieved? I want the executions to be headless so are there any plugins similar to that of Xvfb for windows installations that will help us control the resolution of the slave?